# Any Drawback of using new[1] instead of basic new everytime we need to allocate an object?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create wrapper macros for allocating and de-allocating dynamic memory for my c++ application. So sometime we need to allocate just an object, and sometime need to allocate an array of objects, so we need `new` and `new[size]` respectively, and then we need to remember which delete to call, normal `delete` for objects and `delete[]` for arrays.

So, if I make it generic and always use `new[1]` for single object allocation and `new[size]` for arrays, I won't need to call specific delete in this case, `delete[]` would work all the time.

So my question is that, is there any performance or other drawback of this technique i.e using `new[1]` for single object memory allocation.

Comment: "*I am trying to create wrapper macros for allocating and de-allocating dynamic memory for my c++ application.*" Please don't. Macros obfuscate code, and you shouldn't be (directly) dynamically allocating memory so often that you need to obscure it with something like this.

Comment: Smart pointers is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

First: Please don't. This will obfuscate your code. Consider using memory management support from the STL. For example `std::vector` everywhere you use `new[]` and `std::unique_ptr` everywhere you use `new`. Raw `new` and `delete` are often unnecessary and a frequent source for bugs.

Regarding your question: You will waste memory. Using `new[1]` will allocate a bit more than the size of your allocated object. In front of the returned pointer there will be a bit space that tracks the size of the allocation such that `delete[]` will work without supplying the size to delete since the system can just read this size from the block in front of the pointer. For the user this extra space is pretty much invisible but of course you can feel the wasted memory if you overdo it. Just try the following code and look what the difference in memory consumption is (can ne checked i.e. with valgrind)

```
#include <vector>

// Comment out the following line for the other version
#define ARRNEW

int main () {
    std::vector<int*> ptrs(10000);
    for(int i = 0; i <ptrs.size(); ++i) {
#ifdef ARRNEW
        ptrs[i] = new int[1];
#else
        ptrs[i] = new int;
#endif
    }

    for(auto ptr: ptrs) {
#ifdef ARRNEW
        delete[] ptr;
#else
        delete ptr;
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, Yes you are right, memory would be wasted in this, But to your point "std::vector everywhere you use new[] and std::unique_ptr everywhere you use new". I cant use unique pointers everywhere in my application as there are some usecase in which i need to use union of some raw pointer members, if i use smart pointer inside the union, It would ask to write the constructor the members and the for which member we need to call the constructor varies time to time. So is there any way to cope this?